# prevent this sharepoint javascript running infinitely and on wrong pages

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    //alert("testing");
    //alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
    var username = "";
    var username = $j().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser();
    //alert (username);
    //alert (window.location.href);

if ((username="DOMAIN\username") && (window.location.href="http://godzilla/SitePages/Home.aspx"))
{
window.location = "http://godzilla/central/broadstreet/default.aspx";
}
return false;
else {
return false;
}
});
```

The IF statement should only fire if both conditions are true and quit forever once done.

Testing in Chrome gives the impression it never stops running because the X and reload buttons keep flashing and the if statement also seems to fire even on other site pages -- that is, it tries to redirect again...

What am I doing wrong?? I eventually need multiple if evaluations for multiple user name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error `SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence` at `username = "Domain\username"`. If you escape the `\` by making it `\\` it should get rid of that. Plus unless you want to assign  `Domain\username` to `username` you should probably use `==` rather than the assignment operator `=`

```
if ((username=="Domain\\username") && (window.location.href=="http://godzilla/SitePages/Home.aspx"))
{
    window.location = "http://godzilla/central/broadstreet/default.aspx";
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Whenever you are trying to figure out where your bugs are hit f12 to open the developer console to check for bugs.

Comment: hitting F12 shows console madly blinking on a body scroll statement which I cannot easily copy/paste...suggestions anyone?? I did fix the equals signs...

Comment: Where do I have this error in the code?? "You have a syntax error SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence,"

Comment: @Tom - Sorry I forgot to tell you where the syntax error was. I've updated my answer to include. Basically \u caused it to think you had a unicode string.

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors but now I don't know why the page is still refreshing itself regardless of what page it's on, something's amiss, I don't know what, I posted to Technet.

Comment: @Tom - I'm guessing your default.aspx might be pointing to home.aspx? So it is eternal looping because you are going to the same site. A quick check would be to change the window.location to google.com.

Comment: Code now appears to work correctly though only in Chrome it keeps trying to refresh the page and of course I have no vertical scrollbar in ANY browser, must now figure that out...Thank you, Tom

Comment: look at your height and overflow properties of the elements on the page for the scroll.